# In MuSig-DN why not use a truly random number for the nonce instead of a pseudorandom function?

Tags: schnorr-signatures, random, musig

In [MuSig-DN](https://youtu.be/n19vDaVrwY4?t=207) why not use a truly random number for the nonce instead of a pseudorandom function (PRF)? If the nonce space is big enough it would never be reused.

This question was asked by emzy on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/emzy/status/1336341085233192967?s=20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered by Tim Ruffing on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/real_or_random/status/1336342555336736768?s=20).

> The answer is simply that it's not easy to get truly random numbers
> right in practice. For example, you need to collect entropy in your
> system, and it's hard to write a "test" that checks if your numbers
> are really random.
>
> Broken random number generators have led to numerous real-world
> failures e.g.
>
> https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html
>
> and
>
> https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/08/google-confirms-critical-android-crypto-flaw-used-in-5700-bitcoin-heist/
>
> So it's better to simply avoid real random number generators in
> practice, and this is well-established best practice for "normal"
> single-singer signatures (Schnorr sigs, ECDSA). MuSig-DN makes this
> possible for multisignatures, too.
>
> But your point is correct in theory. If you have a working source of
> truly random numbers, this will just do the job.

Pieter Wuille and Jonas Nick added on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/pwuille/status/1336354130651037697?s=20):

> A working source of random numbers *and* a place to keep them securely
> and tamper-proof between the rounds of the signing process.
>
> Or just a place, to keep a counter securely and tamper-proof between
> the signing *sessions*. Ideally combined with an RNG.

But that is also true for the generation of the private key and we tolerate that there?

> Perfectly right, yes.  I think the answer here is two-fold:
>
> 1. We can at least try to avoid real numbers as much as possible. Even for key
>    generation, we can derive all keys from a single seed, and then we
>    really rely on randomness only once in the life of a wallet for that
>    seed
> 2. It seems that the randomness is particularly brittle when it comes
>    to nonces used in signatures. For example, if you fix a single bit in
>    the nonce, then a few signatures may already be enough to derive the
>    secret key.
>
> And maybe my second point is not even a valid one. I don't know enough about the concrete attacks to tell if signatures become suddenly insecure when we fix a single bit in the secret key (instead of the nonce)?

Diego Aranha added on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/dfaranha/status/1336352607598764036?s=20):

> Your second point is valid when applied to nonces, but a lot more than a few signatures are needed for 1-bit bias (something like 2^60 for an attack of feasible complexity for secp256k1). Fixing bits of the private key should just reduce the key space

And Akira Takahashi added on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/akiratk0355/status/1336419009932259332?s=20):

> Indeed, attacking 1-bit nonce bias of Bitcoin ECDSA is currently out of reach, but 2-bit bias is already exploitable given about one million signatures and 3-bit only requires several thousands (or even less if lattice attack works). Not sure how bad a biased private key can be.
>
> A middle-ground solution would be to include some nonce as PRF input. This way, you retain security even if the nonce is not truly random (proof: https://ia.cr/2016/290) and it should thwart the devastating rewinding attack on Schnorr multisig without ZKP.
>
> But just to be clear, this solution still breaks down once the honest signer reuses the nonce. Dealing with such a stateful scheme is annoying and this is why purely non-stateful solutions like MuSig-DN are preferred in practice.